# How to override perl @INC from command line

Tags: perl

How can I override @INC content with my paths from the command line. If I use "-I" option, it only adds to the default path.

Comment: `@INC` is a List like any other in Perl, you can add to and remove things from it. Also I think the `-l` switch prepends to `@INC`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it is an array, not a list.

Comment: You can't override default values of `@INC` from command line, they are hardcoded to perl binary and can only be changed when you configure perl on install. Or may be not:) Fix me

Comment: -I prepends, so should work for whatever it is you are trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to remove from `@INC`. Modules in earlier paths in `@INC` override modules in later paths, so one normally simply adds to the front of `@INC`

```
export PERL5LIB=path2:path2
script ...

   -or-

PERL5LIB=path2:path2 script ...

   -or-

perl -Mlib=path1,path2 script ...

   -or-

# Doesn't add arch subdirs automatically!
perl -Ipath1 -Ipath2 script ...
```

But it is possible to do what you want.

```
perl -e'
   @INC = grep { ... } @INC;
   do(shift(@ARGV))
      or die "Error attempting to execute script: $@\n";
' script arg arg
```

Replace `...` an an expression that returns true if you want to keep the path in `$_` in `@INC`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export PERL5LIB=/custom/dir:/another/custom/dir;
$ perl script.pl
```